# Recursion Max Depth Exceeded in Terminal BUT NOT in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, recursion, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a couple lines of code that I have tested in a Jupyter notebook, which work great (it runs pretty quickly and there are no issues). I am currently trying to migrate that code into a Flask app, and I encounter a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` when I try to run that particular line of code. That is, the code runs smoothly in the Jupyter Notebook, but not in my Flask app. I took this a step further and tested the line of code just from the interpreter in a terminal and it still fails with the same error.

I am using a virtual environment, so I know that the interpreter is the same across the jupyter notebook, the flask app, and just interpreter in the terminal.

For those that are curious, I am using a terminology package called PyMedTermino, where I am trying to recursively extract a particular sub-hierarchy -- it's like a graph where I recursively collect child nodes from the top down. The code that I am using just leverages the method of the module:

```
>>> from pymedtermino.snomedct import SNOMEDCT
>>> all_disorder_concepts = list(set(list(SNOMEDCT[64572001].descendants())))  # this is the line that fails outside of the jupyter notebook
```

which yields the following error

```
  [Previous line repeated 2981 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Initially, I was thinking that maybe Jupyter sets a higher limit for max memory size, max recursion limit, or the max stack size. I have checked, and there isn't anything different between the recursion limits between the jupyter notebook and the interpreter in the terminal.

```
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()  # this is 3000 for jupyter notebook and the terminal interpreter
```

I can't seem to find a way to check max memory size or stack size (I may not be googling it correctly)... Not too sure where to go next with this.

Comment: The default recursion depth of python isn't 3000, it's 1000 IIRC. Did you look this up?

Comment: In any case, you haven't given a [mcve] so it's tough to answer this

Comment: The code I provided above is the minimal reproducible example -- it's the exact code. If you want to reproduce this, then you would have to install and setup the [Pymedtermino dependency](https://pythonhosted.org/PyMedTermino/)

Comment: @roganjosh that was my understanding as well (that the max depth would be 1000). However, when I ran the `sys.getrecursionlimit()` it was set to 3000

Comment: Can you provide the content of the line that is  `repeated 2981 more times`.  It may provide some clues on which function is involved in the recursion.

Comment: did you try to test it with an increased recursion limit ? (`import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)`).  Perhaps you're just very close to the threshold and it's just a matter of the stack context where you're making the call.  If it still fails, then it probably IS an infinite recursion issue and options set on your SNOMED object may be involved.

Comment: @AlainT. I increased the limit all the way up to 10000 and it was still giving me the recursion error. The line that gets repeated is in `File "/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymedtermino/__init__.py", line 315, in descendants
    for concept in child.descendants():
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]`

Comment: Then the issue is not a function of the recursion limit but must be related to other factors in the environment such as: The Python version, The pymedtermino package version, the OS type/version (e.g end of lines are different between Windows and Unix), the snomed data file or some default options that are different form one environment to another.  Also does the problem occur with all concepts or just that one ?